# Javascript won't wait for firebase data to load

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im retrieving some data from firebase but the code won't wait for the data, it just keep running and some time later it retrieves the data. Im trying with await async but still... Whats wrong? Thanks!

```js
var interlocutor = this.getRandomInterlocutor();
  FriendlyChat.prototype.getRandomInterlocutor = async function(){
    var numberOfUsers = await this.getNumberOfUsersRef();

    console.log('numberOfUsers = ' + numberOfUsers);

    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfUsers);
    console.log('randomIndex = ' + randomIndex);

    var ref = await firebase.database().ref('companies/' + this.company + '/users/');
    ref.limitToFirst(randomIndex).limitToLast(1).once('value').then(snapshot =>
    {
        var user = snapshot.val();
        console.log('getRandomInterlocutor = ' + user); 
    });

  }

FriendlyChat.prototype.getNumberOfUsersRef = async function(){
    var numberOfUsersRef = await firebase.database().ref('companies/' + this.company + '/countregs');
    var numberOfUsers;

    numberOfUsersRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.val());
      numberOfUsers = snapshot.val();
      return numberOfUsers;
    }, function (errorObject) {
      console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    }); 
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things wrong here:

1. You are `await`-ing on the `ref` call, which is not async.
2. You are using `on('value')` which emits a stream of values, not a single read.
3. You are using callback-style code when async/await should be using Promises.

Here's a fixed version of your second function to demonstrate better practices:

```
FriendlyChat.prototype.getNumberOfUsersRef = async function(){
  var numberOfUsersRef = firebase.database()
    .ref('companies')
    .child(this.company)
    .child('countregs');

  try {
    var snapshot = await numberOfUsersRef.once('value');
    return snapshot.val();
  } catch (errorObject) {
    console.log('The read failed:', errorObject.stack);
  } 
}
```